# How to create mnesia table in Elixir?

Tags: database, elixir, mnesia

How to create `:mnesia` table in Elixir?
Is there a way to add indexes while creation?

For example I want to create a User table with few attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
:mnesia.start
:mnesia.create_table(
    User, 
   [{:disc_copies, [node()]}, 
     attributes: [:id, :name, :job], 
     index: [:name, :job]
   ])
```

Note that first attribute will be indexed by default.
For more information, visit [elixirschool.com/en/lessons/specifics/mnesia/#starting-mnesia](http://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/specifics/mnesia/#starting-mnesia)

You also need to create schema before creating the table.
Note that first attribute will be indexedy the node? by default. For more information, visit elixirschool.com/en/lessons/specifics/mnesia/#starting-mnesia

Answer (score 2):

Working with Erlang's Mnesia interface in Elixir can quickly become tiresome. Another option is to use a library like [`Memento`](https://github.com/sheharyarn/memento), [`Amnesia`](https://github.com/meh/amnesia/) or [`EctoMnesia`](https://github.com/Nebo15/ecto_mnesia).

Here's how you would define the table in Memento:

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use Memento.Table, attributes: [:id, :name, :email], index: [:email]
ennd
```

and create it:

```
Memento.Table.create!(MyApp.User)
```

---

***Full Disclosure:** I'm the author of [Memento](https://github.com/sheharyarn/memento).*